# Jquery .hide() or .show() on change event suppresses form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I ran into an incredibly obscure-seeming bug and want to document it for posterity. Here’s what happened:

I’m displaying an HTML form to the user with many text fields and a submit button at bottom. Just above the submit button is a warning message that appears or disappears depending on whether the user has filled in all the required information. During testing (automated using Capybara, or manual in the browser) I fill in each field down the page, then click on the Submit button, but the first click doesn’t register. A *second* click submits the form as expected.

I found that if I disable my custom Javascript, no second click is required. After some process-of-elimination I determined that one Jquery line was responsible for the failure: `$(‘#warning-message’).hide();`. Comment out this line, and filling out and submitting the form works as expected. Re-enable this line, and form submission requires that extra click. What the frak?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out this was because, both during manual testing and when simulated by Capybara-webkit, when you click on an element like a submit button, that’s registered as a specific X/Y coordinate on the screen. You're not clicking on the DOM element, you're clicking on a coordinate. Because of the (lazy) way I set up this page, when I fill out all the required elements then click Submit, upon clicking the submit button *a Jquery `change` event is triggered* which causes `$(‘#warning-message’).hide();`, which in turn causes the submit button to jump up *outside of the area that I had clicked on*, so the submit event never gets triggered in the first place because the browser doesn't realize that I clicked on a button.

I’m still not clear what to make of this, but it’s definitely not a bug per se, so much as a misunderstanding (on my part) of how browser events are handled. I’ve worked around the issue by wrapping the warning div in a fixed-height container so unrelated Jquery change events can't cause the submit button to jump around.

Anyway I hope this helps someone.